# Catching up a lag

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

I am working with multiple computer servers with a database that is distributed across these. Sometimes one of the servers lags behind the rest.

My question is: Is there a word to describe once this lag has been fixed? Caught up? Synchronized (although I think this speaks more to the content than to the state)?

> 1. Server A lags behind the master.
> 2. Server A has **caught up with** the master.

Is this correct or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Can you add an example sentence to your question please?

Comment: I would say "the lag has been reduced" or maybe "has been eliminated" though "caught up" sounds as good to my BrE ears

Comment: Would the pair tardy/timely work?

Comment: Perhaps 'Server A is current'? It's kind of an interesting thought depending on how they actually function. When Server A is behind does the Master wait (block) until A is done running?

Comment: @Ramrod, I like 'Server A is current'. Good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say, "The server is now **up-to-date.**"

> extending up to the present time :  including the latest information ([M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up%20to%20date)

This is similar to Ramrod's comment, but a bit more commmonly used, IMO.

> The sever was lagging for a week but now it is **up-to-date** with the master.

Answer (score 1):

Having worked in (medical) IT for many years, we always just say "the lag has been corrected" or "is gone" ;)  no, there is not any particular word to use though something denoting synchronicity is close... it's not really appropriate to the use with servers and databases in this regard.

Comment: sometimes it helps to come at a problem from a different direction. Your answer speaks to the state of the lag as opposed to the state of the server, but it works and I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Three possible alternatives are:

**[synchronous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synchronous)** (m-w definition):

1. happening, existing, or arising at precisely the same time
2. recurring or operating at exactly the same periods
3. involving or indicating synchronism
4. having the same period; also :  having the same period and phase; b : geostationary
5. of, used in, or being digital communication (as between computers) in which a common timing signal is established that dictates when individual bits can be transmitted and which allows for very high rates of data transfer

**[contemporaneous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contemporaneous)** (running contemporaneously):

1. existing, occurring, or originating during the same time
   contemporaneously adverb

**[concurrent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concurrent)** (running concurrently):

1. operating or occurring at the same time
2. a:  running parallel; b:  convergent; specifically :  meeting or intersecting in a point
3. acting in conjunction
4. exercised over the same matter or area by two different authorities

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Servers are 'synchronised' I would say is the only one that comes close here. Contemporaneous and concurrent both only imply a temporal relationship. But even so, synchronised implies a state and my question refers to the act of having eliminated the lag.

Answer (score 0):

To imply that server A *had to be* synchronized (synced) with the master, you can say:

> Server A has been ***resynced*** with the master.

From Wiktionary:

> *Verb*
>   **[resync](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/resync)**:
>
> *to resynchronize*
>
> *Verb* 
>   **[resynchronize](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/resynchronize)**:
>
> *To synchronize **again***
>
> *Verb*
>   **[synchronize](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/synchronize)** ‎:
>
> (transitive) *To cause two or more events to happen at exactly the
>   same time, at the same rate, or in a time-coordinated way. To
>   harmonize in regard to time.*